# see if there is a key in a map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, find, key

in my function, i have this parameter:

```
map<string,int> *&itemList
```

I want to first check if a key exists. If this key exists obtain the value.
I thought this:

```
map<string,int>::const_iterator it = itemList->find(buf.c_str());
if(it!=itemList->end())
    //how can I get the value corresponding to the key?
```

is the correct way to check whether the key exists?

Comment: @FailedDev I disagree with the proposed duplicate - that question is asking about searching for *values* but this question is about searching for *keys* (and then using the corresponding value, but they're very different questions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is correct way to do this. The value associated with the key is stored in `second` member of `std::map` iterator.

```
map<string,int>::const_iterator it = itemList->find(buf.c_str());
if(it!=itemList->end())
{
  return it->second; // do something with value corresponding to the key
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to iterate through all the items, you can just access the one with the specified key.

```
if ( itemList->find(key) != itemList->end() )
{
   //key is present
   return *itemList[key];  //return value
}
else
{
   //key not present
}
```

EDIT:

The previous version looks up the map twice. A better solution would be:

```
map::iterator<T> it = itemList->find(key);
if ( it != itemList->end() )
{
   //key is present
   return *it;  //return value
}
else
{
   //key not present
}
```

Comment: No need to look up the item twice, either. `find()` returns an iterator to access it directly.

Comment: Don't do that. You are now searching the tree twice. The value is available in find(key)->second (assuming it is not end).

Comment: I knew that, it was just for readability and to show the usage of the [] operator. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Still wrong (or unappropriate), as `*it` returns a key-value pair. The actual value can be retrieved more easily using `it->second` directly. Have you even looked at the 5 points better answer or at least the comments to yours?