# c++ Find map value and key

Tags: c++, dictionary, key

I'm trying to figure out a way to search for a key in a map, return it in a message, get the value of the key found, and return it in another message. For example, the class below has a list of fruits found in a grocery store and I want to create an if than else statement to find the fruitname in the map, return its name in the message below, and then return its price in another output. How can I do this?

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

map<string,double> items;
items["apples"] = 1.56;
items["oranges"] = 2.34;
items["bananas"] = 3.00; 
items["limes"] = 4.45;       
items["grapefruits"] = 6.00;    

string fruit = "apples";

//If a fruit is in map
cout << "Your fruit is: " << "(fruitname value here)"
    <<"\n";
    << "your price is: " <<"(fruitname price here)" 
    << "\n";
 // return the fruitname and its price





  return 0;
}
```

So far I've only seen examples that show how to print entire maps out. The closest I've seen is the one posted at this link(see second post) :[see if there is a key in a map c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858652/see-if-there-is-a-key-in-a-map-c) ,but I'm confused by the syntax,in particular, "buf.c_str()".

Answer (score 2):

Since the keys to the map are `std::string`, you don't have to use `.c_str()`. You could pass the `std::string` object itself:

```
auto it = items.find(fruit); //don't pass fruit.c_str()
if ( it != items.end())
   std::cout << "value = " << it->second << std::endl;
else
   std::cout << ("key '" + fruit + "' not found in the map") << std::endl;
```

Comment: This technique is preferred over `operator[]`. The `operator[]` has the side effect of inserting the element if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It is not only preferred over `operator[]`, it is correct. Using `operator[]` to *find* element would be wrong!

Comment: FYI, I'm talking about the case of `value = items["orange"];`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That would be incorrect. So it is not about *preference* as such.

Comment: @Nawaz since each poster gave similar answer, I'm not quite sure who to give a green check mark to. Each one of them worked when tested but why is "auto" perferred over an iterator like the example that amaurea used?

Comment: @Wormhole99: Figure it out yourself : compare the solutions with and without `auto`. Do you see any difference?

Comment: @Wormhole99: This use of `auto` is a relatively new feature of `C++`. It basically means "store `it` as whatever type `find` returns. That type happens to be a `map<string,double>::iterator`. So they are using an iterator, they are just being less explicit about it. Avoiding long typenames like the one for the iterator above is the main purpose of the new meaning of `auto`.

Comment: Small correction, the value is accessed via: `it->second`

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:

```
auto it = items.find(fruit);

if (it != items.end())
{
    std::cout << "Your fruit is " << it->first << " at price " << it->second ".\n";
}
else
{ 
    std::cout << "No fruit '" << fruit << "' exists.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`s `find` member function.

```
map<string,double>::const_iterator i = items.find(fruit);
if(i != items.end())
    cout << "Your fruit is: " << i->first << "\n" << "your price is: " << i->second << "\n";
```

Comment: When I tried testing this function I got this error:"no match for operator!=" its refering to "if(fruit !=items.end()){".

Comment: @Wormhole88: Sorry, that should have been `i != items.end()`. I have updated the answer.