# C++ convert iterator from map to object pointer

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers

Trying to find an object in a map, and set a member class pointer variable.

```cpp
# Animations.h
#ifndef _ANIMATIONS_H
#define _ANIMATIONS_H

#include <map>
#include "Animation.h"

using namespace std;

class Animations {
  public:
    Animations();
    void add(Animation* animation, string name);
    void play(string name);

    Animation* animation;
    map<string, Animation*> animations;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
# Animations.cpp
...
void Animations::play(string name) {
  std::map<string, Animation*>::iterator itr = animations.find(name);

  if (itr != animations.end()) {
    animation = itr->second;
  }
}
```

I've seen lots of examples with `itr->second` in `couts` and printing, which I've tested, works fine. However I need to convert it to an `Animation *` somehow, but don't know how. When I use the variable from above, it compiles, but the data is all messed up (`frame` should be `0` and instead is some huge int) so probably wrong memory address. I did verify the `frame` of the original `Animation` object is `0`, and a pointer to it is `0` too before adding it to the map.

The closest I've come is this `&(*itr);` via https://stackoverflow.com/a/2160319/1183537 and what I'm doing is close to [c++ Find map value and key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032529/c-find-map-value-and-key) although I want to assign the variable, not just print it out, which are the examples I usually find on `map#find` like https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/ and https://www.guru99.com/cpp-map-stl.html

Can anyone lend some help?

I'm newish to C++, and rusty on C, but programming for 10+ years, so I should be able to handle this.

edit: here's how i'm adding animations:

```cpp
# Animations.cpp
void Animations::add(Animation* animation, string name) {
  animations[name] = animation;

  cout << "> Animations::add " << name << " frame: " << animation->frame << endl;
}
```

and here's how I'm testing the set `animation` pointer:

```cpp
# Animations.cpp
void Animations::update() {
  cout << "> Animations::update" << endl;
  if (animation != NULL) {
    cout << "> Animations::update animation frame: " << animation->frame << " " << animation->width << "x" << animation->height << endl;
    animation->update();
  }
  cout << "> Animations::update done" << endl;
}
```

here's where I was creating the `Animation`s and calling `animations.add`:

```cpp
# Player.cpp
...
void Player::initAnimations(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* sheet) {
  Animation spark(FPS, true, true);
  Animation explosion(FPS / 3, true, true);

  spark.add(sheet, 34, 0, 10, 8);
  spark.add(sheet, 45, 0, 7, 8);
  spark.add(sheet, 54, 0, 9, 8);

  animations.add(&spark, "spark");
  animations.play("spark");
}
```

I've tried not using pointers, from the comment suggestions. But I'm getting error `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Animation'` around the place where I do

```cpp
animation = itr->second;
```

not sure if it needs to be `itr.second` instead, I think I tried both.

Comment: `itr->second` is an `Animation*`.  Your problem is almost certainly elsewhere.  How are you creating the `Animation` objects that you store pointers to, for example?

Comment: Looks like the `Animation*` points to garbage. Where are those animations coming from? Do they need to be pointers? If they do, why not a smart pointer?

Comment: okay, thanks I'll try showing how I'm using `animation`, testing it out

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I'll look into smart pointers, not familiar with those. Can I have a map of `Animation` and not pointers? I'd prefer that anyways, I'll try that too.

Comment: Sure you can. It all depends on what's inside `Animation`. Usually, if it's not polymorphic, it's better to keep values around.

Comment: Two things I'd like to see: how are those `Animation` objects _created_ (i.e. what's passed to `add`), and also, do you initialise the `animation` member to `nullptr` at construction? Otherwise it's going to initially (i.e. before you call `play` once) contain garbage and therefore point to random stuff that, when interpreted as `Animation`, will look like a broken animation.

Comment: yes I intialized `animations = NULL` in the constructor. I'll try `nullptr` instead. I'm having errors while not using pointers, using `map<string, Animation> animations;` instead: `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Animation'` when doing `itr.second` probably.

Comment: As I expected: you're adding the address of a local variable (`spark` dies at the end of `initAnimations`, so any pointer to it becomes invalid). As for `animation = itr->second`, `animation` can stay a pointer, and then you can just do `animation = &itr->second`.

Comment: There's a popular myth: how to write C++ code without learning core C++ fundamental concepts? Answer: run a Google search and copy/paste the results. This only works if the found code's functionality is 100% identical to what's needed. This doesn't work if the found code is junk code, but without learning core C++ fundamentals there's no way to tell if it's junk. And if it's not a 100% match, knowledge of core fundamentals is needed to change it accordingly, but a Google search won't help with this, now, by definition.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are you going somewhere with this comment?

Comment: I'm not copy/pasting @SamVarshavchik, I'm actively learning how to use map's and vectors right now. And clearly I misunderstood local pointers would become invalid. Perhaps I should invest in a C++ book

Comment: okay @EtiennedeMartel I got it working with your suggestions. I just also needed to make a default `Animation()` constructor (i had a custom one). I'll make an answer. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea: [investing in a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: This site might give you a start while waiting for books to arrive : https://www.learncpp.com/.  A tip : recent C++ usually doesn't have all that much new/delete and raw pointers in it. (but uses std::make_unique/std::make_shared). And containers either have (moveable) objects in them (no pointers at all) or unique/shared pointers. This will avoid a lot of bugs because of null pointers and/or forgetting to delete them (memory leaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to non pointers in the map

```cpp
# Animations.h

map<string, Animation> animations;
Animation* animation;
```

while leaving the `animation` a pointer. Then thanks to [@EtiennedMartel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73272190/c-convert-iterator-from-map-to-object-pointer#comment129402884_73272190) I used `&itr->second` to set the `Animation* animation` pointer. The other thing I needed to do was to add a default `Animation()` constructor, which I originally didn't have, which was needed from the map/iterator.

```cpp
# Animations.cpp

void Animations::play(string name) {
  std::map<string, Animation>::iterator itr = animations.find(name);

  if (itr != animations.end())
    animation = &itr->second;
}
```